# SQL Server 2016 Transactional Replication with Service packs on 2 Servers

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016

Transactional replication:

If Server A has Publisher and Distributor with SQL Server Service pack 1 and
Server b is Subscriber with SQL Server 2016 service pack 2

Does publisher and distributor (SQL Server 2016) service pack 1 work with Subscriber (SQL Server 2016) service pack 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, service packs and minor version differences actually don't *usually* matter as far as Replication compatibility is concerned. And with Transactional Replication, the requirement is that the Subscriber and Publisher be within two major versions of each other (in either direction), which the case you described is since they're both the same major version.

This is discussed in [Replication backward compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver16):

> A Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within two versions of the Publisher version. For example: a SQL Server 2012 (11.x) Publisher can have SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Subscribers; and a SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Publisher can have SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and SQL Server 2012 (11.x) Subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for the information :)

Comment: @dba_rs No problem! If you found it helpful, feel free to accept it so others with similar questions find it verified as well.

Comment: sure,will do.. Thanks